# "Schäffer's conjecture" on equation $1^k+2^k+\cdots+x^k=y^n$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations, conjectures, perfect-powers

In 1956 J. J. Schäffer [proved](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485892171) that the equation 
$$1^k+2^k+\cdots+x^k=y^n$$
for fixed integers $k\ge1,n\ge2$ has only finitely many solutions in positive integers unless $(k,n)\in\{(1,2),(3,2),(3,4),(5,2)\}$ [see Theorem 2, p. 27 in the file's numbering of pages]. Furthermore, he conjectured the equation has only trivial solution $x=y=1$ except $(k,n,x,y)=(2,2,24,70)$ (and excluding those four pairs of $(k,n)$).

I was able to find partial results, that the conjecture is true for

1. $k\le11$ [see [this]](https://doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X04000508)
2. $n=2,k\le58$ [mentioned there as well]
3. $k<170$ odd and even $n$ [see this [one]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X06002976)

The newest paper (3.) was published in 2007 and I didn't find newer articles.
So here is my question, is Schäffer's conjecture still an open problem?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.00400.pdf (and the references there) might be of help.

Comment: thx, I found another article https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X1600007X saying Schäffer's conjecture is true for $x<25,n\ge3$